# PHP SQL Delete. Seems solid but won't work

Tags: php, sql

I'm sure it's something simple but I don't have people to turn to for help so here I am :/.

What in the world is wrong with this?

```
<?php
if (isset($_GET['e'])) {

    include_once "connect_to_mysql.php";
    $email = $_GET['e'];

    $sql_delete = mysql_query("DELETE FROM wp_newsman_lst_nickd WHERE email='$email' LIMIT 1");

    if (!$sql_delete) {
        echo "Sorry there seems to be trouble removing your listing. Please email Admin directly using this email address: ***";
    } else {
        echo "It is done. You will not receive our newsletter ever again unless you relist.";
    }
}
?>
```

Comment: Could you paste what your SQL Delete statement looks like?  I do not see anything to assist with.

Comment: do what @JosephCrawford says, and please stop using `mysql_*` use `mysqli_*` or `PDO` please.

Answer (score 2):

A couple of things to note here;

1. You're using the Wordpress core, but you're abstracting yourself away from the WP Database object and using a raw SQL query.
2. You're accepting user input without sanitizing the data; this leaves you vulnerable to injection.
3. You're using the `mysql_` library which is deprecated and will be removed in the next version of php.

Instead, you should use the wpdb object and it's abstractor methods.

```
global $wdpb;
$wdpb->delete('wp_newsman_lst_nickd', array('email' => $email), array('%s'));
```

This will safely delete and provides SQL injection security, as well as utilizing the wordpress core, and also removes the `mysql_` issue, addressing all 3 problems.

Comment: I agree if you are using Wordpress stick to using their conventions and make use of the $wpdb object.

Answer (score 1):

Per your post, your `DELETE` statement looks fine but `'$email'` is most probably `undefined/null` and so the WHERE condition `WHERE email='$email'`  is not matching any rows to delete.

```
DELETE FROM wp_newsman_lst_nickd WHERE email='$email' LIMIT 1
```

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest you stop using the mysql_* and mysqli_* functions and use PDO with bound parameters.  First that SQL looks fine but as stated before $email could be an empty string or a null value.  The BIGGER issue here is you are not doing any validation or escaping on USER INPUT: $_GET['e']  You are WIDE OPEN to SQL INJECTION.

I would suggest you use PDO and bound parameters but here is some sample code to get you started

```
if(!empty($_GET['e']) && array_key_exists('e', $_GET)) {
    $dbh = new PDO('odbc:sample', 'username', 'password');
    $sql = 'DELETE FROM wp_newsman_lst_nickd WHERE email = :email;
    $sth = $dbh->prepare($sql);
    $sth->execute(array(':email' => $_GET['e']));
} else {
    echo '$_GET["e"] is not set properly..';
}
```

Using bound parameters with PDO secures you from SQL injection, though I still suggest you VALIDATE the input to make sure it's not null or an empty string.

As stated above it looks like you are using Wordpress as the CMS (core) for your webiste/system.  I would suggest you stick to their conventions and use the $wpdb object.

More information on that can be found here: https://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/wpdb